# When to use AbortController to remove event listeners?

Tags: javascript

The new [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) API in JavaScript allows us to remove multiple event listeners in one statement. So if we have 20 event listeners, we don't need to write 20 `removeEventListener()`; we can simply write `controller.abort();` to remove them all.

Now, I'm wondering in what situations I'd be able to take advantage of this feature in a real application. I've never needed to remove a large number of event listeners at once.

(I already know that abort() can also be used to cancel a fetch request)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER:**
The answer given below was based on the Mozilla [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController). After some research, I found that there is in fact a way to remove an event listener with the AbortController Constructor.  It's a new [chrome88](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-chrome-88/#more) feature release (Jan 2021) and may not have full adoption across all browsers yet, so the preferred method is still the old answer below.

The AbortController method was tested and seems to work in chrome & edge as of 09/21.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3> Check the JS-Console</h3>
    <button class="button" name="button1">Btn 1</button>
    <button class="button" name="button2">Btn 2</button>
    <button class="button" name="button3">Btn 3</button>
    <button id="remove-btn">Remove Listener</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
const removeListenerBtn = document.getElementById('remove-btn');

const controller = new AbortController;

for(let element of buttons) {
    element.addEventListener('click', (event) =>{
        console.log(event.target.name, "clicked")
    }, { signal: controller.signal })
}

removeListenerBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
    controller.abort()
})
```

**OLD ANSWER:**
The Abort Controller object is for aborting fetch calls, not for removing event listeners. If you need to remove multiple listener's here's one way of doing it.

This example grabs all DOM elements that contain the class def "button" then attaches an event listener using a for loop.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3> Check the JS-Console</h3>
    <button class="button" name="button1">Button 1</button>
    <button class="button" name="button2">Button 2</button>
    <button class="button" name="button3">Button 3</button>
    <button id="remove">Remove All Listeners</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
const removeListeners = document.getElementById('remove');

buttons.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener("click", doSomthing)
});

removeListeners.addEventListener("click", removeList)

function removeList(){
    buttons.forEach(element => {
        element.removeEventListener("click", doSomthing)
    });
}

function doSomthing(e){
    console.log(e.target.name, "clicked");
}
```

Comment: @Monster Cat If this answers your question, can you please mark this as the answer?

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer my question. Abort controller can be used to remove event listeners too. And I wanted to know when it's preferred compared to the old approach. Thanks for the answer though I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: @MonsterCat I went ahead and updated my answer.