# Turn addeventlistener on and off

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm not a very good programmer put managed to port a dos program to windows and then from windows to javascript running is a browser starting 2014. I have some keydown event listeners that run based on a preferences .js file at startup. I would like to add disable and enable buttons to turn the listener off and on if possible (I know hijacking the Ctrl and Shift may seem questionable to some)

```
if (usectrlshiftdnup) {

 // Trying to get Shift key 16 to step up a graph data set which works

 document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
   if (event.keyCode === 16) {

     document.activeElement.blur();
     document.getElementById("upbutton").click(); 
     document.activeElement.blur();

   }
 });

 // Trying to get Ctrl key 17  to step down a graph data set which works

 document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
   if (event.keyCode === 17) {

     document.activeElement.blur();
     document.getElementById("dnbutton").click(); 
     document.activeElement.blur();

   }
 });
```

I'm usually a trial and error programmer, have done some reading about removeEvenListener, but thought I would just ask this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce a layer of abstraction to manage the currently active listener callbacks. Something like a `ListenerManager`.

```js
class ListenerManager {
    listeners = [];

    storeListener(typeString, callback) {
        this.listeners.push([typeString, callback]);
        // Note that this function also automatically "enables" the stored listener
        document.addEventListener(typeString, callback);
    }

    enableListeners() {
        this.listeners.forEach((listener) => document.addEventListener(listener[0], listener[1]));
    }

    disableListeners() {
        this.listeners.forEach((listener) => document.removeEventListener(listener[0], listener[1]));
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```js
let manager = new ListenerManager();
manager.storeListener("keydown", myCallback1);
manager.storeListener("keydown", myCallback2);

// Let's say you want to disable them all
manager.disableListeners();

// Later you want to enable them all again
manager.enableListeners();
```

---

Alternatively, you could do this at a higher level, which may be simpler albeit less efficient. Simply use a global boolean variable that all your relevant callbacks manually check to determine whether they should ignore input.

```js
let isEventsDisabled = false;

// Your callbacks would look something like:
function myCallback1(event) {
    // Guard clauses
    if (isEventsDisabled) return; // Relevant callbacks have this added for "disabling"
    if (event.keyCode !== 16) return;

    document.activeElement.blur();
    document.getElementById("upbutton").click(); 
    document.activeElement.blur();
}

// And you would register listeners "directly" the same way you have been doing
document.addEventListener("keydown", myCallback1);

// Let's say you want to disable them all
isEventsDisabled = true;

// Later you want to enable them all again
isEventsDisabled = false;
```

Comment: OK, Thank you. I will try and work with these suggestions. I had tried to add a third parameter ,true); to the addEventListener and then calling removeEventListener with a third parameter also , true); but that did not work or kick any console errors.

Comment: I pretty much understand you 1st example and your 2nd somewhat. I was thinking I should give my event parameter functions discreet names like myCallback1 and myCallback2. (event1 and event2)

Comment: The third optional parameter, if passed as a boolean, just changes the way the event fires (event capturing; you may read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#:~:text=with%20the%20listener.-,useCapture,-Optional), but it's not really relevant to your use case and is safe to not specify).

Comment: It is good that if you added with `true`, you also removed with `true`, but the problem may have been copy-pasting your callback - you end up creating two separate lambdas that do the same thing. Crucially, they are not the same function object, so the attempted removal fails to remove the initially added function. Yes, you should give each callback a name so that you are able to properly remove it later.

Comment: The global boolean variable in the 2nd example is just something you are free to make up as a programmer (it's not part of any API). Think of it as answering the question: "Should I ignore inputs right now?". So by default, we set the answer to false. Whenever we want to ignore inputs, we set it to true. But to use that answer, we need to actually ask the question. Where do we ask it? In all your callbacks. So each callback *checks* the boolean variable with an `if` statement to "ask" the question. If it should ignore, then don't proceed; if it shouldn't ignore, proceed as normal.

Comment: OK Thank you Cloud!

Comment: Cloud, Works like a charm! And Elegant! As a mostly amature  programmer I really envy folks like you. I had to put var listeners = []; above the class declaration as console was kicking listeners.push as listeners undefined. Actually, I have been a career Piano Technician for 50 years and made the mistake of writing a graphical Piano String analysis program in 1990 (clipper with graphing library), ported to Windows in 1996, finally porting to javascript/browser in 2014 using AMCharts. Been supporting the program for Piano Rebuilders since day one Thank you so much!!! Got lazy this time.

Comment: Glad to help. Interesting story. I think the undefined error can be fixed by using `this.listeners` inside the class methods - typo on my part. I'll edit the answer accordingly. Then you don't have to put a `var listeners` outside the class itself. If you have the source code hosted somewhere, I would be curious to take a look.

Comment: This is outdated. There is now the `AbortController`, it's way easier to use, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68967007/when-to-use-abortcontroller-to-remove-event-listeners

Comment: Yes adding this. to listeners.push allows declaring the array inside the class. It works as you have suggested and corrected. I don't have the source posted anywhere (runs locally). However, the concept of porting a standalone windows application to javascript/browser makes the app cross platform and I suspect there may be many situations where this might apply in a positive way. I'm going to try triggering it from onFocus() and onBlur() within a textbox and textarea. The only other question might be disabling only one of what is in the array like listener[0]. Im thinking pop and push somehow.

Comment: Ah so that's why you're disabling the listeners, for typing I presume. And needing individual disabling would explain adding multiple separate listeners for the same event. If you don't have too many listeners, and need individual disablement, then it could be easier to just forgo the manager and write some convenience functions that each add/remove one of the named callbacks. Eg `enableShift()`, `disableShift()`, `enableControl()`, `disableControl()` etc. As long as the callbacks you pass aren't duplicated, this will work.

Comment: Thank you Cloud! I have 8 keydown listeners Ctrl/Shift, F1/F2, [/], which all step dn or up a note on a graph to show/edit string scale data. Esc to clear data in data grid and F9 to re-plot the graph. Most turned on or off in an editable setup file. All data are numbers except for a notes file with Piano info thus disable shift/Ctrl for Caps and paste. Your solution takes care of what I need. Legacy uses miss type over and I've yet to find a solution for that thus Esc to blank fields. Thank you again. I'm brand new to Stack Overflow but it has helped many times since moving to javascript.

Comment: listeners = []; inside the class declaration kicks a closure compiler error Declaring var listeners = []; before the class declaration and removing this. before the next 3 listeners statements compiles with the closure compiler with no errors and seems to run as expected.